# Accessing nested array in Formik FieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

**EDIT: Please check the updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/network-config-wrlcz), it incorporates some of the changes suggested in the below answer. **

I'm using Formik and its [`<FieldArray ../>`](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray) component to handle some nested data to render inputs. I can't quite figure out what exact string to pass to the name prop in `<FieldArray name={ // here}`.

In my component I have a user selection that filters out some data and returns this array.

```
"chosenDevice": [
  {
    "deviceName": "eth0",
    "macAddress": "01:40:27:0F:2E:CB",
    "ipv4DHCP": false,
    "ipv4Addresses": [
      "182.148.1.100/24"
    ],
    "ipv4Gateway": "",
    "ipv6DHCP": false,
    "ipv6Addresses": [
      "232.232.2/100/10"
    ],
    "ipv6Gateway": ""
  }
]
```

I want to access the `ipv4Addresses` array. I'm either passing the wrong string to `name` or not using index in `.map` properly. Currently I have the following:

```
    <FieldArray
  name={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses[${index}]`}
>
  {({ remove, push }) => (
    <>
      <div>
        {values.chosenDevice.length > 0 &&
          values.chosenDevice.map(
            (ipv4Addresses, index) => (
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex"
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                <label
                  htmlFor={`chosenDevice[${index}].ipv4Addresses`}
                  className="custom-label"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                >
                  ipv4Address(es)
                  <Field
                    className="custom-input"
                    name={`chosenDevice[${index}].ipv4Addresses`}
                    placeholder="< ipv4Address >"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </label>
                <ErrorMessage
                  name={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses`}
                  component="div"
                  className="field-error"
                />
```

I have a [codesanbox that may provide some more context.](https://codesandbox.io/s/network-config-wrlcz)

After looking into this further, basically I need to provide the string value of `deviceName[0].ipv4Addresses[0]`, so I may need to rethink the .map and what it's actually returning.

Answer (score 4):

With a `.map` inside of another `.map`, you might be getting `index` values confused. Try naming `index` something more specific to each `.map` (such as `deviceIndex` and `addressIndex`). I've used `addressIndex` for the inner map operation in my answer below.

---

It seems like your `<FieldArray>` here should only concern itself with the `ipv4Addresses` array on the current `chosenDevice` object.

Try this:

```
<FieldArray
  name="chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses"
>
  {({ remove, push }) => (
    <>
      <div>
        {chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses > 0 &&
          chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses.map(
            (ipv4Address, addressIndex) => (
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex"
                }}
                key={addressIndex}
              >
                <label
                  htmlFor={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                  className="custom-label"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                >
                  ipv4Address(es)
                  <Field
                    className="custom-input"
                    name={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                    placeholder="< ipv4Address >"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </label>
                <ErrorMessage
                  name={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                  component="div"
                  className="field-error"
                />
```

But if I'm wrong about that, and the `<FieldArray>` tag *does* need to reference which `chosenDevice` it's a child of, this should do it:

```
<FieldArray
  name={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses`}
>
  {({ remove, push }) => (
    <>
      <div>
        {chosenDevice[index].ipv4Addresses > 0 &&
          chosenDevice[index].ipv4Addresses.map(
            (ipv4Address, addressIndex) => (
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex"
                }}
                key={addressIndex}
              >
                <label
                  htmlFor={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                  className="custom-label"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                >
                  ipv4Address(es)
                  <Field
                    className="custom-input"
                    name={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                    placeholder="< ipv4Address >"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </label>
                <ErrorMessage
                  name={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses.${addressIndex}`}
                  component="div"
                  className="field-error"
                />
```

Comment: @dj2 I've updated my answer just now with a few syntax corrections. Sorry about the initial errors.

Comment: I've tried both solutions in my codesandbox example and the field doesn't seem to render with the changes. Did you fork the sandbox by any chance?

Comment: The second solution, it's just pushing an empty string to the array without actually rendering another input box.

Comment: The map is working correctly because I added > 1 ipv4Address and it's display them in separate fields. So the `remove(ipv4Index)` may need to be changed

Comment: Any more thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<FieldArray name={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses[${index}]`}>
```

The `index` here if you are trying to use from the map below, then this is wrong you'll not get index outside the map.

Use this map above the `FieldArray`, like this:

```
values.chosenDevice.map((ipv4Addresses, index) => (
 <FieldArray
  name={`ipv4Addresses[${index}]`}
>
  {({ remove, push }) => (
    <>
      <div>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex"
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                <label
                  htmlFor={`chosenDevice[${index}].ipv4Addresses`}
                  className="custom-label"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                >
                  ipv4Address(es)
                  <Field
                    className="custom-input"
                    name={`chosenDevice[${index}].ipv4Addresses`}
                    placeholder="< ipv4Address >"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </label>
                <ErrorMessage
                  name={`chosenDevice.${index}.ipv4Addresses`}
                  component="div"
                  className="field-error"
                />)
```

Comment: Trying these changes, I am not able to add additional fields for `ipv4Addresses`. Additionally, when there are 2+ addresses being read in, both the strings are in one input instead of two.

Comment: If you are saying so then I suggest you use state for accessing index outside map
   <FieldArray
      name={`ipv4Addresses[${index}]`}

Comment: I have updated the sandbox with your suggested changes https://codesandbox.io/s/network-config-wrlcz.

Comment: Tried using state?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [configIdx, setConfigIdx] = useState(0);

 <FieldArray
           name={`chosenDevice.ipv4Addresses[${configIdx}]`}
                                    >
                                      {({ remove, push }) => (
                                        <>
                                          <div>
                                            {values.chosenDevice.length > 0 &&
                                              values.chosenDevice.map(
                                                (ipv4Addresses, index) => {
                                                  setConfigIdx(index);
                                                  return (
                                                    <div
                                                      style={{
                                                        display: "flex"
                                                      }}
                                                      key={index}
                                                    >
                                                      <label
```

See how I updating state, this might help to achieve your result.

Comment: Are you able to update the sandbox? I've tried several approaches with no success.

Comment: Yes but locally

Comment: Can you fork it and paste the link with your updates?

Comment: That I can't promise because my system is off now but you can copy above code and paste it appropriately